# VBA copy a value afer plus "+"

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with VBA
Actually, I need to copy a value after plus "+" in a sum, for example "=2000+5000", I need to copy only "5000" and paste in another cell.

I have this code already:

```
Dim cell As String
Dim aPos As Integer
Dim bPos As String
Dim result As String
Dim ex As String
Dim cPos As String
Dim dPos As String

Range("a1").NumberFormat = "@"
cell = Range("A1")
    aPos = InStr(cell, "+")
    bPos = Right(cell, aPos)
        Range("b2").NumberFormat = "@" '
        Range("B2").Value = bPos
ex = Range("b2")
    cPos = InStr(ex, "+")
    dPos = Left(ex, cPos)
        Range("b3").NumberFormat = "General"
        Range("b3").Value = dPos


End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I have this code already" - so what's wrong with it?

Comment: Seems to me that `Split(Range("A1").Formula, "+")(1)` does the trick too without all that hassle =)

Comment: Aside from there being much simpler ways to achieve your goal, you should know that you're deriving `bPos` incorrectly. With your design, it will only work if the two numbers are equal in length. It should read something like `bPos = Right(cell, Len(cell)-aPos)`.

Comment: @CLR, on top of that, if OP is interested in the formula behind a value, using `NumberFormat` transforms the output into a value which is not backed by a formula nomore. Meaning `aPos` is not even going to find a hit ;). `.Formula` is most likely what OP is after.

Answer (score 2):

If all your values are 2 operators like `2000+5000` create your own UDF:

```
Function GET_SECOND_OPERATOR(ByVal vRng As Range) As Double
GET_SECOND_OPERATOR = CDbl(Split(vRng.Formula, "+")(1))
End Function
```

[image]

Try to adapt this to your needs. Right now this UDF only works if selected cell is a single cell. There is no error handling.